# Cannot get translation path views

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, uri

I used drupal 6.25 and views and translation modules .

I do not know why not I am not getting my translation path but another page translated.

I noticed I created 2 views but I cannot get the translated path view in page

http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/fa/world
**Home » World » علمی**
translated path view in page
http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/fa/entertainment
**خانه » پژوهشی » پژوهشی**